# Ionic 2 Geolocation set another location when position not available

Tags: google-maps, angular, ionic-framework, geolocation, ionic2

```
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {

      let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      //let latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.987469, 29.027119);

      let mapOptions = {
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 15,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      }
      this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapElement.nativeElement, mapOptions);
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error getting location', error);

    });
```

I am trying to check if user's position is available or not. When the user's gps is open, the code above works. But I need to check if GPS is not open and I will set a location by myself when I cannot get the location of the user. How should I check if the user location available or not ? I am using ionic-native geolocation. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Diagnostic` cordova  [plugin.](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/diagnostic/)

```
Diagnostic.isLocationEnabled().then( (avail) => {
  console.log(avail);
  if(!avail){
    return Diagnostic.switchToLocationSettings();
  }
}).catch( (err) => {
  console.log(err);
}).then( () => {
  console.log('entered');
  return this.getLocation().then(()=>{ //get location } )

  })
```

Comment: I have done that, but still there is problem. Ionic application switches to settings just once when the application is installed. When I turn on GPS, everything works fine. But after that when I turn off the gps and close the app and open it again, it does not switch to settings or does not ask for location permission.

Comment: Did you try this solution? If this is run when the application needs location,it will bring gps settings to switch on gps when its switched off.

Comment: Yes I tried, but it bring gps settings only once after the app installed and it does not bring gps settings anymore.

Comment: This is the code which I use in my app and it works. The app should have permission to use location.

Answer (score 1):

You can get current position using this code. I was getting same problem. Resolved using this code:

```
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        var options = {
            timeout: 10000,
            enableHighAccuracy: false
        };

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position=> {
            console.info('Position : ' + JSON.stringify(position));

        }, error => {
            console.log(' Error : ' + JSON.stringify(error));
        }, options);
    } else {
         // you can set your custom position here if not location found.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need pass `options` to `Geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` for throw `catch`

Try this

```
let optionsGPS = {timeout: 4000, enableHighAccuracy: true};
Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(optionsGPS).then((result) => {
  this.loadMap(result.coords.latitude, result.coords.longitude);
}).catch((err) => {
    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
        title: 'Error on GPS',
        subTitle: err,
        buttons: 'OK'
    });
    alert.present();
});
```

I had the same problem, and this worked for me

Comment: not working got position error in the console timeout expired?