# ionic2: geolocation in browser fails with error: EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): false

Tags: ionic-framework, firefox-addon, ionic2

I am working with geolocation plugin with ionic2. When the app loads in the browser, it asks for permission. But it does not get the position when getcurrentposition is called. I use FireFox browser.

The console log shows the error:

> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): false

I need to pass the location if available or null to another function based on success or failure of the getcurrentlocation call.

Here is the code snippet:

```
 public test(){
 Geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {

 console.log (resp.coords.latitude);
 console.log (resp.coords.longitude);

  this.callclockin(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);    
 }).catch((error) => {
  this.callclockin("", "");   
 });
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The plugin `Geolocation` is for device mobile

And for throw the `catch` in a device mobile look at my other answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41825400/ionic-2-geolocation-set-another-location-when-position-not-available/41831455#41831455)